# Finding the minimum difference between two elements with recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to make a "shortest distance algorithm for 1D".

However, I'm confused on the recursive case. I don't know how to get the value back after the recursive calls (lines 14 and 15). How can I fix the following code?

```py
def recCPairDist(points):
    if len(points) == 1:
        return 0
    elif len(points)== 2:
        abs(points[1]-points[0])
        #how do i assign the result final value back to "leftDist rightDist"
        #since its a recurisive, the result can be more than 1, should i store all the result in a list first?
        #then get the min(list)?

    else:
        mid = len(points) // 2
        first_half = points[:mid]
        second_half = points[mid:]
        leftDist = recCPairDist(first_half)
        rightDist = recCPairDist(second_half)
        midDist = abs(second_half[0] - first_half[1]) #i dont think this is correct since i didnt consider the recursion
        return min(leftDist,rightDist,midDist)

def cPairDist(points):
    points.sort()
    return recCPairDist(points)

P1 = [7, 4, 12, 14, 2, 10, 16, 6]

cPairDist(P1)
```

The expected result for P1 should be 1, since the shortest distance would be between 7 and 6.

Comment: Are you trying to find the smallest distance (absolute difference) between two values? Is recursion required? (I personally don't think recursion is the best way to solve this problem, but if you want to use recursion for educational purposes, it's totally cool.)

Comment: yes, absolute difference! yup im practicing recurison here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close! There's three things you have to do:

1. For the case where there's only one point to consider, you should *not* return `0`. For example, for the array `[3, 6, 9]`, the answer is 3, but your given base case will return `0`. This is because one of the resulting subarrays will be of length 1 for odd-length arrays, and the zero return value will propagate when you return from each recursive call.
2. You need to return the value `abs(points[1]-points[0])` in the `len == 2` base case explicitly using the `return` keyword.
3. For your recursive case, the minimum difference must be between two consecutive elements in the left half, two consecutive elements in the right half, or between the last element of the first half and the first element of the second half (two consecutive elements in the original array, but not covered in the two recursive cases). So, your `midDist` should compute this value.

Here is a code snippet that resolves all three of these issues:

```py
def recCPairDist(points):
    if len(points) == 1:
        return float('inf')
    elif len(points)== 2:
        return abs(points[1]-points[0])
    else:
        mid = len(points) // 2
        first_half = points[:mid]
        second_half = points[mid:]
        leftDist = recCPairDist(first_half)
        rightDist = recCPairDist(second_half)
        midDist = abs(first_half[-1] - second_half[0])
        return min(leftDist,rightDist,midDist)
```